# How to check for specific keyword/value pairs in any order

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string: `String s = "a=182 b=41 c=72"`, contains only: a b c, with their respective values, but they can occur in random order. How do I go about doing this?

I have tried doing the following:
`(?=a\\=(\\d+))\\s+(?=b\\=(\\d+))\\s+(?=c\\=(\\d+))`

Comment: Must it be only `abc` and exactly once for each?

Comment: Do you want to get  a match if the string is `"My text is: a=182 b=41 c=72 and more text here"`? Can either `a`, `b` or `c` go missing? Right now the best way is to split with whitespace and then split with `=`.

Comment: Probably have to use captured groups and then iterate through the groups to see if exactly one of each pair was detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:(\\s*[abc]=)(?!.*\\1)\\d+){3}$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQlpMI/1)**

**[JAVA Code](https://regex101.com/r/zQlpMI/1/codegen?language=java)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?:(\\s*[abc]=)(?!.*\\1)\\d+){3}`

  - `(\\s*[abc]=)` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace followed by either `a` or `b` or `c` followed by `=`. This whole submatch is captured in Group 1.
  - `(?!.*\\1)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current match is not followed by the contents of group 1 anywhere later in the string
  - `\\d+` - matches 1+ digits
  - `{3}` - repeats the subpattern 3 times once each for `a`, `b`, `c`
- `$` - asserts the end of the line

Comment: Just in case spaces can be missing, then the `^(?:(\\s*[abc]=)(?!.*\\1)\\d+){3}$` regex [will also match](https://regex101.com/r/zQlpMI/2) `a=182 b=41b=72`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can avoid that if I modify the pattern to [`^([abc]\s*=)(?!.*\1)\d+(?:\s+([abc]\s*=)(?!.*\2)\d+){2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/zQlpMI/3)

Answer (score 0):

If your string always contain space you can split them into array like this

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
```

and then check first char of each array element.